# How do I build the database connection string if the website is on the same server as the db?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, database-connection, connection-string

I have a problem with my connection string and I couldn't find anything on the web that could help me. So I have a test website on which I connect to a database which is not on the same server. There it all works fine, the data is being read correctly and the connection is successful.

Now when I try the same on a website which is on the same server than the database it doesn't work. So I figured I can't just connect to the database server as I would from a different server if I am already on that server like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="nameOfConnString" connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=databaseName;User ID=userName;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Could anyone help me with that?

If you need more information just ask please.

Thanks in advance!

**[edit]**

Oh I forgot...this is the error message I get:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Can you check with `Data Source=(local)`

Comment: Your connection string *should* work. Can you connect to the database using Management Studio ?

Comment: Maybe your server doesn't know its own name?  Trying pining that server name from the command line.  If it can't resolve the name then it sounds like there's a name resolution problem for the server admin(s) to fix.

Comment: Just like the error message says, you have a configuration issue with SQL Server - it's attempting to use a communication protocol that's not turned on in the SQL Server configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `localhost` instead of `server name`

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="nameOfConnString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=databaseName;User ID=userName;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: ok, both - your solution and the one above work, now I only get an ItemTemplate error because of the ListView I'm using!

Answer (score 2):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="nameOfConnString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=databaseName;User ID=userName;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both answers above are correct, however, if you have SQL Express installed (I assume we're talking about MS SQL) then your connection string must be something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="nameOfConnString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=databaseName;User ID=userName;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```